# Connect Cosmos DB Flow to Power Apps

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, powerapps, power-automate

I want to create a PowerApp to display my Cosmos DB Data in a pretty way and to edit some data to send it back to the Cosmos.

To get the data I use a Logic Flow. It's triggered by an PowerApp event. Afterwards I do a 'Query document V2' call and with the 'response' I want to parse it to a json:

[image]

When I now try to add this flow to a button in my app, this error appears:

[image]

Is this error ocurred to someone before or have somebody another solution for my problem?

Thank you already and stay healthy!

With best regards
Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

On the step after CosmosDB connector you have already had a response from the Cosmos. You should use to response from there, not to map something with HttpConnector.